# Are Tintin questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about [The Adventures of Tintin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Tintin). Wikipedia says

> Its well-researched plots straddle a variety of genres:
>   swashbuckling adventures with elements of **fantasy**, [...]

But I'm not sure if there is enough fantasy to be on-topic here.

Comment: Tintin was primarily mystery. Check out my Stack Exchange [Area 51  proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86331/mystery-and-detective-fiction) about that.

Comment: By way of comparison we do have a few *Asterix* questions: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46147/in-the-asterix-series-why-didnt-the-romans-just-address-the-magic-potion-probl 
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83570/does-the-twelve-tasks-of-asterix-take-place-in-the-same-universe-as-the-rest-o

Comment: [Flight 714](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_714) is certainly on-topic. It's even got a [UFO](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-lnweWDUwmEo/UXBwYPFtOhI/AAAAAAAAAfE/ydrKXLlCEWg/s1600/photo.gif).

Comment: General policy: [Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic? (e.g. spy movies)](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e/344#344)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's certainly a considerable amount of Fantasy (and even Sci-fi) involved in the various Tintin books. As with most "genre-based" stories, question about those elements are absolutely 100% on-topic.

[image] [image]

Questions about non sci-fi or fantasy elements, however are probably off-topic as they would fall under general literature.

- On-topic: What are the mysterious shooting stars in "The Shooting Star"?
- Off-topic: What is Captain Haddock's favorite brand of whisky?

And as always, if you're in doubt you can always 'trial' the question out in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) *before* posting it on the main site. You'll get a prompt response and plenty of feedback, I'm sure.

Comment: Oh, my question wasn't about fantastic elements. I will try to think other ones.

Comment: @Oriol - If it's off-topic for the main site, you can still ask it in chat.

Comment: @Oriol The consensus was that [the question does not need to be about a sci-fi/fantasy element of a work](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6594/5184).

Comment: Richard, your answer seems to contradict @phantom42's comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: Point 3 in [this list](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/344/20774) would seem more appropriate; "*If the question is specifically about an sf-nal element, even if it's only a minor part of the work, it's on-topic.*"